# I couldn't find any solutions for my TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

In this code below here, i wanted to create a guessing game. Player enters 4 numbers and the computer tells the player how many numbers are correct. But when i run the program, just after I input a number it gives me "TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()" error. I've read about this error but I couldn't find any solutions. Any help to solve? And how to solve please?

```
import random

numbers = int(random.randrange(1000,9999))
nums = [int(x) for x in str(numbers)]

while True:
    try:    
        guess = int(input('Enter your guess: '))
        mynumbers = [int(k) for k in str(guess)]
        i = 0

        if int(guess) == int(numbers):
            print('Congragulations, you have guessed the number!')
            print('It took [] tries to guess')
            break
        else:
            a = len((mynumbers) in (nums))
            print ('*' * a)

            i+=1
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print('Please enter a number.')
        continue
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `len((mynumbers) in (nums))`? What are you expecting that to return?

Comment: [Count duplicates between 2 lists](//stackoverflow.com/q/4775004)

Comment: i want it to return a number that shows how many numbers are guessed true. for example: let's imagine the random number is "1234" and we gave "3456" to input, i want it to return (2) and print " ** "

Comment: And what makes you think that `len((mynumbers) in (nums))` will do any of those things?

Comment: I thought it would search for each number. But I've missed that it was a function that delivers True or False. I still don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `((mynumbers) in (nums))` will return Boolean so cannot call `len()`

For what you want to do

**try:**

`a = sum([x in nums for x in mynumbers])`

It will count number of digits you guess correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
((mynumbers) in (nums))
```

delivers True or False -> Here you can't use the len()-command

edit:
The solution should be anything like this:

```
counter=0
for i in mynumbers:
     if i in nums:
         print i
         counter+=1
print counter
```

The counter should be your result then

Comment: Thank you, I've completely missed that. How can I do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

you need a for loop in your else statement.

```
...

else:
    number_of_rights = 0
    for index in mynumbers:
        if index in nums:
            number_of_rights += 1
    print ('*' * number_of_rights)

...
```